# Switch case within switch case in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift grammar question.
I have a switch case in the function, and I need to make a nested switch case something like below.

```
func changeIcon(status: String){
    switch status {
    case "ready", "recording", "finished", "error":
        if indicator.isAnimating {
            indicator.stopAnimating()
            indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        }
        indicator.isHidden = true
        symbolImageView.isHidden = false
        
        switch status{
        case "ready":
            symbolImageView.image = Images.streamIsReady
        case "recording":
            symbolImageView.image = Images.streamIsOngoing
        case "finished":
            symbolImageView.image = Images.close
        case "error":
            symbolImageView.image = Image.error
        default:
            print("default")
        }
        
    case "init":
        symbolImageView.isHidden = true
        indicator.isHidden = false
        indicator.startAnimating()
    
    default:
        print("default")
    }
}
```

I want to use a switch case (or if statement is also fine if it's possible) for checking if I display UIimage or UIActivityIndicator, and then use another switch case to determine which UIImage should I display. I was wondering if using a nested switch case is redundant and there is an alternative way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: First of all, you should use an `enum`. It sees that `init` should not be part of the enum at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a function, for example

```
func changeIcon(status: String) {
    switch status{
    case "ready":
        updateImage(.streamIsReady)
    case "recording":
        updateImage(.streamIsOngoing)
    case "finished":
        updateImage(.close)
    case "error":
        updateImage(.error)
        
    case "init":
        symbolImageView.isHidden = true
        indicator.isHidden = false
        indicator.startAnimating()
        
    default:
        print("default")
    }
}

func updateImage(_ image : Images){
    if indicator.isAnimating {
        indicator.stopAnimating()
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    }
    indicator.isHidden = true
    symbolImageView.isHidden = false
    symbolImageView.image = image
}
```

And I agree with Sulthan: Use an enum rather than a String

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should have an `enum`:

```
enum Status: String {
   // "init" renamed to "loading"
   case loading, ready, recording, finished, error

   var icon: UIImage? {
       switch self {
       case .loading:
           return nil
       case .ready:
           return Images.streamIsReady
       case .recording:
           return Images.streamIsOngoing
       case .finished:
           return Images.close
       case .error:
           return Image.error
       }
   }
}
```

Then your code can become:

```
func changeIcon(status: Status) {
    if status == .loading {
       indicator.startAnimating()
    } else {
       indicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    let icon = status.icon
    symbolImageView.isHidden = icon == nil
    symbolImageView.image = icon
}
```

Statement `indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true` should be part of your view setup and not inside this function.

Comment: There’s also no good reason for the enum to have a string value. But either way, the enum means you can’t have invalid cases through spelling.

Comment: @gnasher729 Well, `RawRepresentable` also defines equality but you are right that I could just use `Equatable`. I usually prefer `String` enums in my code though.